# Library to import openAPI Specs

Tags: node.js, express, openapi

i got a openAPI Specification.
is there a library for nodeJS to use this Specs to not type all the API requests separate?

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate a Node.js server stub and/or client SDK from an OpenAPI definition? Or something else? I'm afraid your post is unclear.

Comment: nodeJS app should be a client to fetch data from an api.

Answer (score 1):

[openapi-typescript-codegen](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen) works pretty well. There are quite a few options so you can generate a fully typed SDK for your project.